# Network routing issue

Tags: router, routing

Here is the situation.
I've turned server ns1 (a dual-homed linux box) into a router by enabling ip_forwarding on it (echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward)

**Server ns1:**

eth0: 10.10.0.200/24 (default gw: 10.10.0.51)

eth1: 192.168.53.198/24 (I've not set any default gw for this interface)

*Routing table on server ns1:*

```
[root@ns1 ~]# netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.53.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth1
0.0.0.0         10.10.0.51      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

I'm trying to ping a webserver (having an ip of 10.10.0.54) from a workstation BUT NOT SUCCEEDING.

**Workstation:**

The properties of workstation are:

eth0: 192.168.53.150/24

default gateway: 192.168.53.198

*Here is the routing table on my workstation:*

```
root@workpc:~# netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.53.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.53.198  0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

Why is my workstation not able to reach 10.10.0.54? I believe I've setup everything correctly.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Can you ping 10.10.0.54 from ns1?  What does `traceroute 10.10.0.54` from the workstation tell you?